# C++ - getter function returns 0?

Tags: c++

The class:

```
class Process
{
public:
   void setTime(int temp);
   int getTime();
private:
   int myTime;    
}
```

The Functions

```
Process::Process()
{
   myTime = 0;
}
void Process::setTime(int temp)
{
   myTime = temp;
}
int Process::getTime()
{
   return myTime;
}
```

Main just has the Process object and sets a number as well as gets.
Couple of friends and I have been trying to figure out why the get function is returning zero.

The actual code is on my other computer and I can't get to it at the moment.

I am doing things in a while loop if that helps. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you post a complete, compilable program?

Comment: Wait until you're able to access the code, then come back and revise the question. At the moment, it's impossible to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Okay, will do. In the meantime, have you ever hear of a getter function returning the initial value made by the constructor regardless of what the setter is?

Comment: Another question I have is, how would I ask my question without revealing my entire code? I tried to set it up with the kind of problem I am having because this pertains to my entire homework project. I don't want to show my entire code because I've been working very hard at it. I just don't understand why some of my setters and getters work perfectly find and this one doesn't. I just don't know how to show the forum without spilling my entire code.

Comment: @rtdickey  show the function call of your getter and setter along with the value of `temp`, ( also best if you show us how you are assigning the value for `temp` ).

Comment: @rtdickey _"... have you ever hear of a getter ..."_ No, your getter setter functions look fine. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: This is the worst of the two kinds of common problems.  The first is, "there's a bug in my code.  debug it for me, and tell me what's wrong".  The second is, "there's a bug in my code, but I don't have the code handy.  Debug it for me, and tell me what's wrong".

Comment: Chances are you're calling the getter and setter on two different objects, but in a way that's not obvious (perhaps via a temporary or something).  But that's just a guess.  You can post example code without posting the whole thing by doing some work to pare down your code to just the essentials that still show the problem.  That's a basic troubleshooting technique and is not unique to posting a question on stackoverflow.  As a matter of fact, it's not unique to programming.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to define the constructor inside the class itself since the variable being private..or try using this.myTime..or may be because you call the get method before the set...

Comment: The code he posted is perfectly fine on these regards.

Comment: @zneak, the code is not fine.  The constructor is defined but not declared.  However, this is not the question being asked...